# 11ty - How do I display post / page year?

Tags: date, nunjucks, eleventy

I'm using Eleventy and using Posts. I have set the date in the meta data using the format

`date: 2021-09-10`.

I can display the full date using

`{{ page.date | readableDate }}`

But **I want to display just the year** (YYYY) within the post content. I'm using Nunjucks.

How do i do this?

I've tried

`{{ page.date.getFullYear }}`

This gives the following error:

`function () { for (var _len2 = arguments.length, args = new Array(_len2), _key2 = 0; _key2 < _len2; _key2++) { args[_key2] = arguments[_key2]; } return obj[val].apply(obj, args); }`

Any help would be really appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a filter to your .eleventy.js file

```
eleventyConfig.addFilter("justYear", (dateString) => {
  dateObj = new Date(dateString);
  return DateTime.fromJSDate(dateObj, { zone: 'utc' }).toFormat('yyyy');
});
```

Then in your .njk file

```
{{ page.date | justYear }}
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for your help Mathias. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: I get error: 'ReferenceError: DateTime is not defined (via Template render error)`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your approach is going in the right direction, and you don’t need to register a filter just for that.

However `page.date.getFullYear` is a function, and what you did is just printing its body instead of executing it.

The following works just fine, note the parentheses after the function name:

```
{{ page.date.getFullYear() }}
```

Tested with Eleventy >=2.0.x, but should work with earlier versions as well.